How to use bi3d freespace isaac ros?
I am using Isaac ROS on my laptop with a RTX2060. I have driver version 560.35.03. I am running a docker container for running the nodes. A realsense D455 is used as the camera. I have got the example to run successfully but the output occupancy map does not really make much sense.
Launched using the following command
ros2 launch isaac_ros_examples isaac_ros_examples.launch.py launch_fragments:=realsense_stereo_rect,bi3d,bi3d_freespace \
interface_specs_file:=${ISAAC_ROS_WS}/isaac_ros_assets/isaac_ros_bi3d_freespace/realsense_quickstart_interface_specs.json \
featnet_engine_file_path:=${ISAAC_ROS_WS}/isaac_ros_assets/models/bi3d_proximity_segmentation/featnet.plan \
segnet_engine_file_path:=${ISAAC_ROS_WS}/isaac_ros_assets/models/bi3d_proximity_segmentation/segnet.plan \
max_disparity_values:=10 publish_default_tf:=true 


In the image the bottle (metal cylinder looking object) is placed 2 feet from the camera. But the distance in the output measures to be 2.5m. Is this the expected behaviour or am I doing something wrong here? Adjusting the camera a bit higher reduces the distance to 1.8m but this is still much higher than the expected value. Is there a scaling factor that I need to be aware of?
